# how to achieve same compression in linux and windows

Tags: linux, java, compression, zip

I have a example.jar file.
  I'm trying update a class file in the jar.
  when I'm packing the class file using jar or zip utility(**command line-linux**)

> I tried :
>
> jar uf my MyJarFile.jar MyclassFile.class
>
> zip -u my MyJarFile.jar MyclassFile.class

I get some checksum assume XXYYZZ.

But when I pack the same class file in windows using **7zip(GUI)** I get different checksum say MMNNOO.
  This is because of change in compression ratio.I mean size also differs.

Now my question is how can I achieve same compression ratio **ie same checksum**.

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried jar in both platform. both produces different cksum...  :(

Comment: Compression ratio and checksum are nothing to do with each other. In a ZIP file the checksum is of the uncompressed data, so it wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Well, first I'd try using 7zip on both platforms, or jar on both platforms (and use the same tool to calc the CRCs, as methods vary widely), or else you are always comparing apples to elephants. Even then though, I'm almost certian that you will end up with differant CRCs just due to characteristics of the file storage, like the filesystem and the relation of file data to filesystem metadata which vary widely between NTFS and EXT4.

Answer (score 3):

The checksum is a hash of all the bits contained in the file.

Windows and Linux/UNIX use different file endings, so creating a checksum on each OS with the same tool will always produce a different checksum, unless you specifically change the line ending.

To check if you have the same compression ratio, look at the file size.

The might be very slightly different, but it should be minimal.

The point of checksums is not to see if 2 files created at different times or in different places are the same, it's to check if somebody or something has changed a file.

If I was to send you a zip, I could checksum it, then email you the zip and the checksum I created.

You received the zip, checksum it again, and if the checksums match, the file has not changed since I'd sent it.

EDIT - I'm assuming with this answer that the JAR was compiled and zipped on Linux, and also compiled and zipped on Windows

Comment: Line endings? Zip files don't have line endings.

Comment: True, but whatever is contained in the zip file (if it's a jar, bytecode) has line endings, as would any text file in the jar.

Comment: Bytecode doesn't have line endings either, because it's bytecode, not source code. But regardless, even if it had, zip never changes line endings by default, not unless you explicitly enable that mode).

Comment: Java class files containing byte code have line endings in them based on the architecture the class was compiled on. If you compile a java program and open the class file in Notepad++ and set it to show end of line chars, you will see LF for UNIX compiled classes, and CR LF for windows ones. The class is still essentially an ASCII file. Those line endings are chars in their own right, so they will be compressed into the ZIP file, so the content is different, leading to a different checksum.